# NVIDIA GTX 660M on 14.04 64-bit

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-drivers, nvidia-current-dev

I have checked the other questions on here (e.g. [Nvidia driver for GeForce GTX 660](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283789/nvidia-driver-for-geforce-gtx-660)), yet nothing has provided any help. Generally, what happens is that I get nvidia-current downloaded and installed, but whenever I reboot, x does not come up and I am sent to a text-only login. Starting X manually does not work either. The only thing to do is to purge all nvidia content. Any ideas/help?

Comment: Try the Bumblebee driver: http://bumblebee-project.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bumblebee did not work for me. What did work, however, was the suggestion made in this thread ([How to set up nVidia Optimus/Bumblebee in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04)), taken from this website (http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html). Namely:

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```