# drivers | is modprobe necessary when installing nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, 15.10

I'm trying to install the latest and stable proprietary Nvidia drivers for my newly built Skylake PC. It is running on Ubuntu 15.10. My VGA card id Nvidia GTX 660.

First I tried installing the drivers using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

It's installing a legacy driver 304.128 but not the latest one. Then I purged all the nividia packages `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` and tried installing `sudo apt-get install nvidia-355`

When installing the drivers 355 the installation is giving me some errors about corrupted packages and the whole system crashes thus I couldn't get the error details as well.

So what I'm doing wrong here? Do I have to install it as a module to kernel as specified [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/283939/299686)? And why the current driver is a legacy driver (304.128)

Note: I haven't add any ppa, just went with the drivers that came with the distro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa add this ppa and install 355 and then reboot, you will need modprobe if you need to do CUDA or opencl.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyhow do you know a way of knowing if I need CUDA or opencl?

Comment: If you do programs like Blender, pycuda, Darktable, you will need either opencl or CUDA yes.

Comment: A small question again. There is already a nvidia 355 driver, it's labeled as proprietary in Software & Updates (is must have came with the distro, since I don't have any additional ppas). Apparently this graphics-drivers ppa has a 355 driver too. So when I do a apt-get install nvidia-355 which driver from which source is going to install?

Comment: It seems to be working now. Running on 355.11 driver

Comment: Depending on the date, it would select whichever is stamped new and usually it would be the ppa. Thats good as you will then get regular updates to the series.